# mail inline style in loop are replace by '?' in php

Tags: php, email, html-email

I have a php script that create a table with custom color as background,

here is some part of the code:

```
foreach($cells as $cell) {
    $html .= "<td style='width:".$cell['width']."%; height: 20px ; border:1px solid black ; background-color:" . $cell['color'] . "' > </td>";
}
```

but when the email is generated i got this:

```
<TR>
    ...
    <TD style="BORDER-TOP: black 1px solid; HEIGHT: 20px; BORDER-RIGHT: black 1px solid; WIDTH: 0.15%; BORDER-BOTTOM: black 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: black 1px solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #dbdbdb"></TD>
    <TD style="BORDER-TOP: black 1px solid; HEIGHT: 20px; BORDER-RIGHT: black 1px solid; WIDTH: 0.15%; BORDER-BOTTOM: black 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: black 1px solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: orange"></TD>
    <TD ?width:0.15%;height:20px;border:1pxsolidblack;background-color:Green?=""></TD>
    <TD style="BORDER-TOP: black 1px solid; HEIGHT: 20px; BORDER-RIGHT: black 1px solid; WIDTH: 0.15%; BORDER-BOTTOM: black 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: black 1px solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: green"></TD>
    ...
</TR>
```

I have absolutely no idea where the '?' come from and no idea how to fix it.

EDIT: added ; at the end of the line fix it.

```
$html .= "<td style='width:".$cell['width']."%; height: 20px ; border:1px solid black ; background-color:" . $cell['color'] . ";' > </td>";
```

Comment: Are you sure that your generated code is actually being generated by the code above?  I notice that your "<td... " above becomes <TD... in the generated code; or is there some other process in between the two examples?

Comment: Yes ! I open the mail on IE to debug it.

Comment: Also I use the same HTML to be displayed on a page and it works, this problem only happens when i send the html via mail..

Comment: I think you need to trace the output further back than looking at it in IE. Verify what is actually being sent by your code, rather than what is being received in IE, because there are things that could affect it along the way, and you don't want to be hunting in your source code for a solution if it turns out to be a network proxy trying to do something useful.

Comment: Off topic, but I would add that inline styles like this are really not good practice; move them out to a `<style>` element and give your HTML elements classes as necessary instead. You'll save yourself a lot of bandwidth and also make your code a lot easier to read and work with.

Comment: @Simba it would be awesome if that worked haha, unfortunately it's a script for generating HTML email and <style> aren't well supported.

Comment: Yes it is. I'm not talking about an external style.css file (which I agree can be a problem), I'm talking about a style element within the HTML containing your CSS. The stylesheet is still in the same document as the HTML, and it does work just fine everywhere that supports CSS at all, including the crustiest of email clients.